# Get max value in pair

Tags: java

I have many pairs with form:

- itemid core
- 1       2
- 1       4
- 1       3
- 2       2
- 2       5

I want to get max score for other itemid
result

- itemid core
- 1       4
- 2       5

Solution?

Comment: Is this in some database or you want to achieve this result in java??

Comment: -1 as you did not try anything.

Comment: @n99o - SO is not a place to ask people to write programs for you.  It is a place where programmers ask questions to help the code for themselves.

Comment: @Stephen C : I dont think the problem is in him as he is asking a question without trying . But the problem is in the person with reputation more than 15000 is giving a whole solution directly.

Comment: @vikiiii - the problem is both.  If the OP hadn't asked, then the answer would not have been posted.  Note that the OP didn't ask for help ... he specifically asked for a solution.

Comment: @vikiiii - also it is instructive to look at the other questions that this guy has asked.  I'm seeing a clear pattern ...

Comment: @StephenC : I agree the problem is in both.

Answer (score 2):

Use a [`Map<Integer, Integer>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) with the `itemid` as the key, and `max(core)` as its value, and in each iteration, compare the current [maximum](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#max%28int,%20int%29) value with the new `core`:

```
Map<Integer, Integer> maxMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
int[][] pairs = {
        { 1, 2 },
        { 1, 4 },
        { 1, 3 },
        { 2, 2 },
        { 2, 5 }
};
// Calculate max value for each itemid
for (int i = 0; i < pairs.length; i++) {
    int[] pair = pairs[i];
    Integer currentMax = maxMap.get(pair[0]);
    if (currentMax == null) {
        currentMax = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    }
    maxMap.put(pair[0], Math.max(pair[1], currentMax));
}
// Print them
for (Integer itemId : maxMap.keySet()) {
    System.out.printf("%d %d\n", itemId, maxMap.get(itemId)); 
}
```

This will print:

```
1 4
2 5
```

**[DEMO](http://ideone.com/rM5uA)**.

Comment: Please don't encourage lazy Questions by providing potted answers.

Answer (score 2):

This would give you a sorted List of Pairs, here sorted in ascending order by core:

```
package com.pair.sort;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;


public class MainClass {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Pair> list = new ArrayList<Pair>();
    list.add(new Pair(1, 2));
    list.add(new Pair(1, 4));
    list.add(new Pair(1, 3));
    list.add(new Pair(2, 2));
    list.add(new Pair(2, 5));
    Collections.sort(list);
    System.out.println(list);
}

}

class Pair implements Comparable<Pair>{

public Pair(int i, int j) {
    itemId = i;
    core = j;
}

Integer itemId;

Integer core;

@Override
public String toString(){
    return itemId + " " + core;
}

public int compareTo(Pair compare) {
    return core.compareTo(compare.core);
}
}
```

Comment: Please don't encourage lazy Questions by providing potted answers.

Answer (score 0):

You may sort list of items by itemid first and if itemid is equal by core next.
Once you have sorted list it'll take O(n) to go through all elements and pickup max for equal itemid.
let me know if you need actual code.

If it's SQL.
select itemid, max(core) from table
group by itemid.